# Why is my discord bot not sending a daily message

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio

Obviously some code is missing but here is all of it that should be needed to help.

```
import os
import discord
import requests
import json
import asyncio

channel_id = 791884298810163200

def get_quote():
    response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    quote = json_data[0]["q"] + " -" + json_data[0]["a"]
    return quote

async def sendQuote():
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(get_quote())


async def background_task():
    #if not 8am, wait until 8am (ignoring the seconds place, doesn't have to be exactly 8am)
    await sendQuote() #fix this
    await asyncio.sleep(5) #change this to the number of seconds in a twenty four hour period when done testing
    await background_task()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client.loop.create_task(background_task())
    keep_alive()
    client.run(my_secret)
```

I have not added the wait until 8 am section yet as its not required in testing. if I move `channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)`
`await channel.send(get_quote())` into on_ready() it prints the quote so im really not sure whats going wrong in sendQuote()

My error is:

```
Task exception was never retrieved future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<background_task() done, defined at main.py:31> exception=AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'")> Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 33, in background_task await sendQuote()
#fix this File "main.py", line 28, in sendQuote await channel.send(get_quote()) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send
```

Comment: Hi @joseph-spielman, please [edit] your question and move that above comment into the question.

Comment: Shouldn't  you be having this await call 'await bot.wait_until_ready()' in your 'sendQuote()'. So it can wait till the bot is ready i.e., to execute the 'on_ready()' function.

Comment: Not a big user of async/await, but I have a huge feeling something is wrong with that code... First of all, why are you calling background_task() inside the same background_task() method? You've effectively made it recursive, for what?! Second, if you need to run your code once per day - god forbid, don't make a timer in your program, just use the system task scheduler, it's available both on Windows and Linux, and it will make your code plain & simple. Lastly, if you still believe you require this design, I'd suggest putting some debug print, start from pprint(channel) before line 28

Comment: If you want something to send every once in a while just run a `while True` loop inside an `async` function, put an `await asyncio.sleep(x)` inside the loop, and then do `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(client.start(my_secret), daily_loop(), ...))`. `asyncio.gather` basically takes a bunch of async function calls (do **not** `await` them) and then makes them concurrent so you can then use `loop.run_until_complete` to run them all together.

Answer (score 1):

I executed your code and the only issue is not awaiting for `client.wait_until_ready()` which I had mentioned in my [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69533427/why-is-my-discord-bot-not-sending-a-daily-message#comment122903143_69533427). Before the `on_ready()` as the client/bot is still being setup, the `channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)` returns `None` which results in the below `Attribute Error`.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Please find full info on the `wait_until_ready` or `on_ready` API calls in [discordpy official documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_until_ready).

Below is the complete code with slight modifications that worked for me,

```
import os
import discord
import requests
import json
import asyncio

channel_id = 000000000000000000
client = discord.Client()

def get_quote():
    response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    quote = json_data[0]["q"] + " -" + json_data[0]["a"]
    return quote

async def sendQuote():
    # wait till the client has executed on_ready().
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(get_quote())


async def background_task():
    #if not 8am, wait until 8am (ignoring the seconds place, doesn't have to be exactly 8am)
    await sendQuote() #fix this
    await asyncio.sleep(5) #change this to the number of seconds in a twenty four hour period when done testing
    await background_task()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client.loop.create_task(background_task())
    #keep_alive() - unknown function code, so commented it in here.
    client.run(my_secret)
```

Comment: Thank you, I found another way to do it, however I will be changing back to this method because it is much less code then how I ended up getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing isn't a good idea.
You're doing a recursive call of `background_task()` this will work for some time, but you'll run into a recursion error earlier or later and your code will fail.

have a look into the `Tasks` extension from discord.py this offers functions for reoccurring tasks, exactly as you want it :)

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html